# Help!!! Cannot boot any version after 10.04

Tags: boot, 14.04

My motherboard is ASRock B75M R2.0. Last time I used Ubuntu 12.04, but after jacking a broken HDD in my PC, Ubuntu stopped booting. Now no version after Ubuntu 10.04 boots in my PC.

I've tried (almost) every possible way to boot but failed. Now I'm using Windows 7. Please help me to get back in to my beloved Ubuntu.

I've got blackscreen problem. after booting started a white dash(-) start beeping in the left top corner. then it gets smaller(i think probably after detecting my GPU) and after few seconds of that screen freezes. sometime even my restart button dont work. i tried booting from pendrive and DVD, but the result is same. i tried live booting, direct installing, installing using wubi. but same result

Comment: Hard to tell. What problem do you get when you boot ? Error message ? black screen ?

Comment: have you tried boot-repair? post some more info about what exactly happens, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I've got blackscreen problem. after booting started a white dash(-) start beeping in the left top corner. then it gets smaller(i think probably after detecting my GPU) and after few seconds of that screen freezes. sometime even my restart button dont work. i tried booting from pendrive and DVD, but the result is same. i tried live booting, direct installing, installing using wubi. but same result.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue. Did you ever find a resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these steps:

- Disable all other boot devices in your bios except the specific ones
  you'll be using (Builtin CD/DVD drive and Hard Drive.)
- Try changing your RAM speed to something lower.
- Also try taking one of the RAM chips (or sets of chips) out to see if
  the problem is in one of the chips.

Comment: how can i change RAM speed? Do i need to change my ram? i have only one ram of 4GB.

Comment: This is done at bootup in the bios.  You can get into the bios in most computers, depending on the manufacturer a trigger key when the computer starts to boot.  Examples are Del, F1, Esc, etc.  What is your motherboard's manufacturer?  Check the ram speed specification of your chip and make sure your bios isn't set higher.  The speed settings may be one of, 133, 400, 800, 1066Mhz.  Also ensure your computer isn't overheating.

Comment: Well finally i've got the solution by creating another problem. If i unplug my DVD-R, ubuntu boots without any problem. but cannot boot with the DVD rom pluged-in. Plz help.

Comment: I edited my answer.  Try the first item in the list to resolve this boot problem.